# Ubuntu 18.04 small screen glitches after resume from suspend

Tags: 18.04, suspend, amd-graphics

As I said in title it happens after resuming from suspend mode. I'm using open source drivers to AMD RX 570 8GB OC. I tried to fix this by installing amdgpu-pro (proprietary drivers) but the issue remained.

I also get this on startup log (I don't know what is it or if it has something to do with the problem):

```
amdgpu 0000:1f:00.0: Invalid PCI ROM header signature: expecting 0xaa55, got 0xffff
```

Also, running `hwinfo --display`:

```
Model: "ATI Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480]"
Vendor: pci 0x1002 "ATI Technologies Inc"
Device: pci 0x67df "Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480]"
```

If you notice my card is RX 570 but the system recognizes it as RX 470/480. Is this normal?

The only way I can solve this is rebooting the system. Otherwise it keeps happening which is a little annoying.